# Create a stored procedure where the primary key is 'None' for my identified database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm a new SQL developer and I'm attempting to write a stored procedure that selects from my databases system views and where I need to get the following results:

I want to select my

1. database name
2. schema name
3. table name
4. primary key column (uses a function to return 'None' if no primary key)
5. identity column (uses case statement to return 'No Identity' if NORMALIZE columns are identity.

Example results:

```
Database     Table     Schema     Primary Key     Identity
-------------------------------------------------------------
DB1          Table1    dbo        None            No Identity
DB1          Table2    dbo        abcID           abcID
```

I have my function (see bottom), but I'm having issues on where to use it.  I'm also having issues getting my CASE statement right.

Here's my script so far:

```
CREATE PROC System_Views_Databases_Without_Primary_Keys
     @DBName NVARCHAR(255)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        db_name () AS [Database],
        SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
        tab.Name AS [Table],
        tc.TABLE_NAME AS [Primary Key],
        col.is.identity AS [Identity]
    FROM
        sys.columns col
    JOIN 
        sys.tables tab ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
    JOIN 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON tab.name = tc.table_name
    WHERE 
        OBJECTPROPERTY(tab.object_id, 'TableHasPrimaryKey') = 1
        CASE
           WHEN [Identity] = 1 THEN 'Yes Identity'
           WHEN [Identity] = 0 THEN 'No Identity'
        END
```

My DDL for function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Primary_Key] (@Primary_Key VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR (255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nonvalid varchar (255)

    IF @Primary_Key IS NULL 
       SET @nonvalid = 'None'
    ELSE 
       SET @nonvalid = @Primary_Key

    RETURN @nonvalid
END
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will give you each column in the table and tell which one is identity and which one is primarykey.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        db_name () AS [Database],
        SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
        tab.Name AS [Table],
        col.name,
        Case when COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(tab.name),col.name,'isidentity') = 1 then col.name Else 'No Identity' End AS [Identity]
        ,Case when Prim.CONSTRAINT_NAME is not null then prim.CONSTRAINT_NAME else 'None' End as Primarykey

    FROM
        sys.columns col
    JOIN 
        sys.tables tab 
            ON col.object_id = tab.object_id
   Left JOIN (
                SELECT K.TABLE_NAME,
                K.COLUMN_NAME,
                K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K
                ON C.TABLE_NAME = K.TABLE_NAME
                AND C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                AND C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                ) prim 
            on prim.TABLE_NAME = tab.name and prim.column_name=col.name
```

Comment: no problem. not sure why you would need that unless you are doing normalization.